# What do you call a person who is always quick on the draw and never let anyone offend him/ her?

Tags: vocabulary

There are some people who are good at repartee, especially if someone wants to criticise them,they straight away respond to those critics in order not to get offended, or let them offend him/her.
Are there any words in English to describe such people or personalities?

Answer (score 1):

**quick-witted**; adjective; able to reply in a clever or funny way without thinking for a long time

Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quick-witted)

Comment: What about a negative way of it?

Comment: being funny does not just imply a positive. Sarcasm is also humour . sarcasm; noun; the use of remarks that clearly mean the opposite of what they say, made in order to hurt someone's feelings or **to criticize something in a humorous way**:

Comment: The opposite would be **dim witted**, resulting a person who may be a **dim wit**.  These are offensive terms.  Use them with caution.

Answer (score 0):

You can say the person has an **acerbic wit**. It means the person has the ability to speak in a critical and direct way.
But note that it is a literary expression (high vocabulary) and most people would not understand what it means.